# Installing individual packages from Solaris .iso

Tags: package-management, solaris

I need to update the following packages:

```
SUNWjaf
SUNWjato
SUNWjmail
```

I read that the updated versions of these packages can be found on the latest version of Solaris, and that it's possible to just install the specific packages I want.

I can only find them as directories in the .iso and they all have the following structure:

```
|-- archive
|   |-- none.7z
|-- install
|   |-- copyright
|   |-- depend
|   |-- i.none
|-- pkginfo
|-- pkgmap
|-- reloc
```

Is it possible to install these as some sort of package? Or turn them into a .pkg?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They already are a package - simply use `pkgadd -d /path/to/cdrom/Product SUNWjaf SUNWjato SUNWjmail` or whatever the parent directory is containing those subdirectories.